# C# HTTP GET remote JSON data then parse it

Tags: c#, json, http

I don't really know how to ask this but basically,

I have a domain with a JSON file `http://example.com/data.json`
and I would like to fetch the data from `/data.json` and "convert it to text".
The remote JSON file contains the following: `{"CurrentVersion": "1.0"}`
and I would like to parse **CurrentVersion** and define a string with its value (1.0).

Comment: So you want to deserialise the JSON to an object that you can read the value of CurrentVersion?

Comment: Please include any code that you already have including your attempt to read the value.

Comment: Yeah something like that

Comment: You can just read the file and save it as a string. There should be enough posts on this site which explain how to do that.

Comment: We know a question has been answered to your satisfaction when you Accept an answer. There's no need to edit the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>One possibility is to make use of `System.Net.WebClient` for downloading the data:</strike> (Outdated, see Edit below.)

```cs
// WebClient is outdated
string json;
using(var webClient = new WebClient())
{
   json = webClient.DownloadString("http://URL.com/filename.json");
}
```

after downloading the string you can deserialize it with a framework like [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com). Because it is a simple JSON file we can deserialize it into a dictionary. This way we do not have to create an explicit class for it:

```cs
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

Now we can access the version like this:

```cs
var versionString = dict["CurrentVersion"];
```

---

**Edit**
Like @CodeCaster stated in the comments: The usage of `System.Net.WebClient` is outdated. Instead one should use [`System.Net.Http.HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient). Downloading the JSON could then look something like this:

```cs
// HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use.
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

[...]

var json = _httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://URL.com/filename.json");

// Do something with JSON
```

Comment: [_"We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class"_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks for the hint, I updated my answer.